# How to delete an object in an array of an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a function that deletes an object within a nested array of an object which is within an array...

How would I delete one of the schedules by date?

```
state = {
children: [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Bella',
    lastName: 'Laupama',
    profile: 'child_care',
    schedules: [
      {
        date: '25 December, 2018',
        parent: 'Chris',
        activity: 'Christmas'
      },
      {
        date: '28 December, 2018',
        parent: 'Mischa',
        activity: 'Christmas with Malane Whanau'
      },
      {
        date: '31 December, 2018',
        parent: 'Laura',
        activity: 'New Years Eve'
      },
      {
        date: '1 January, 2019',
        parent: 'Laura',
        activity: 'New Years Day'
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Would something like this work?...

```
delSched = (firstName, date) => {
  let children = [...this.state.children]
  let findChild = children.find(child => child.firstName == firstName)
  let newState = findChild.filter(sched => sched.date !== date)
  this.setState({
    children: newState
  })
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Even though most of these solutions would most probably work, the one I could get working was thank you to @Marius. I used a modified version of his code.

```
delSched = (firstName, date) => {
    var children = this.state.children

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      var child = this.state.children[i]

      if (child.firstName == firstName) {
        //Loop through the schedules
        for (var k = 0; k < child.schedules.length; k++) {
          var schedule = child.schedules[k]

          //remove schedule if date == date
          if (schedule.date == date) {
            child.schedules.splice(k, 1)
          }
          this.setState({children})
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting? Please state a reason in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good ol' for loops. The newer Array prototypes are good, but not supported everywhere. Plus having it in a loop, you can change things if you need.

Working example:

```
var state = {
  children: [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'Bella',
      lastName: 'Laupama',
      profile: 'child_care',
      schedules: [
        {
          date: '25 December, 2018',
          parent: 'Chris',
          activity: 'Christmas'
        },
        {
          date: '28 December, 2018',
          parent: 'Mischa',
          activity: 'Christmas with Malane Whanau'
        },
        {
          date: '31 December, 2018',
          parent: 'Laura',
          activity: 'New Years Eve'
        },
        {
          date: '1 January, 2019',
          parent: 'Laura',
          activity: 'New Years Day'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var children = state.children;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = state.children[i];

  if (child.firstName == "Bella") {

    //Loop through the schedules
    for (var k = 0; k < child.schedules.length; k++) {
      var schedule = child.schedules[k];

      //remove schedule if date == date
      if (schedule.date == "25 December, 2018") {
        child.schedules.splice(k, 1);
      }

    }

  }
}

console.log(state);
```

Comment: YES! thank you so much @Marius, this worked perfectly with slight modifications...

I will edit my original post to show the modification.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fixed:

```
delSched = (firstName, date) => {
  const children = state.children;
  const findChild = children.find(child => child.firstName === firstName)
  const newSched = findChild.filter(sched => sched.date !== date)
  findChild.schedules = newSched;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Gatsby, how would I return this to state? - The 5th line sort of confuses me on what to do?

Comment: @Tearz When you change a reference to an object, it will also change the actual object. `findChild.schedules = newSched;` will change `state.children[0 or whatever].schedules`

Comment: it seems to crash when I try and use this? - would you mind maybe having a look for me if I gave you the repo?

Comment: @Tearz Yes. I will.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, with a small correction:

```
delSched = (firstName, date) => {
  let children = [...this.state.children]
  let findChild = children.find(child => child.firstName == firstName)
  let newState = findChild;
  newState.schedules = newState.schedules.filter(sched => sched.date !== date)
  this.setState({
    children: newState
  })
}
```

Your `findChild` is the object that contains the `schedules` array, you need to go one level deeper to grab the array and use `filter` on it

Comment: Thanks Velimir, but I think this seems to delete the schedules as a whole?

After I do this, it crashes the schedules.map within a parent component.

Comment: state does not equal findChild.schedules. It should not be placing it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it slightly shorter by doing something like this:

```js
let state = { children: [{ id: 1, firstName: 'Bella', lastName: 'Laupama', profile: 'child_care', schedules: [{ date: '25 December, 2018', parent: 'Chris', activity: 'Christmas' }, { date: '28 December, 2018', parent: 'Mischa', activity: 'Christmas with Malane Whanau' }, { date: '31 December, 2018', parent: 'Laura', activity: 'New Years Eve' }, { date: '1 January, 2019', parent: 'Laura', activity: 'New Years Day' } ] }] }

const delSchedule = (arr, name, date) => {
  let f = arr.find(x => x.firstName == name) 
  f.schedules = f ? f.schedules.filter(y => y.date != date) : f.schedules
}

this.setState({
  children: delSchedule(this.state.children, 'Bella', '1 January, 2019')
})
```

This way `delSchedule` is not modifying the state but returns the new one which you assign in `this.setState` etc.

Comment: Thank you @Akrion for your response, however, I'm really struggling to find a way to make this work as I'm not sure how to make this work without it being just one single function?

Comment: Not sure I understand ... you want to change the state inside `delSchedule`?

Comment: Kind of yeah, I'm setting the state from within the function, much like this...

    delSched = (firstName, date) => {
        let children = [...this.state.children]
        let findChild = children.find(child => child.firstName == firstName)
        let newState = findChild;
        newState.schedules = newState.schedules.filter(sched => sched.date !== date)
        this.setState({
          children: newState
        })
      }

Answer (score 0):

You probably searched for sth like:

```
delSched = (firstName, date) => {
  let newChildren = this.state.children.map( child => {
    // don't modify other people
    if( child.firstName != firstName ) return child;

    // new object
    let newChild = {...child}
    // mutate schedule by date
    newChild.schedules = child.schedules.filter(sched => sched.date !== date)
    console.log(newChild);
    return newChild
  })
  this.setState({
    children: newChildren
  }, () => console.log(this.state.children) )
}
```

[Working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a87m6a)